# Attempting to Delete Blob in Storage Container from Azure Data Factory Results in 409 Conflict Error

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that ingests XML files and when its done with them moves them to an archive folder.

[image]

We had some issues with the Soft Delete option so we switched it off, but now we're left with the issue where the Copy data step works but the Delete step returns a 409 Conflict error.

This link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/301686/delete-activity-delete-blob-returns-conflict-(409)
Mentions filenames as being a possible cause so in the copy step I added a prefix "archived_" to the filename, but this made no differece.

I've also set the retry option on the Delete activity to 3, same results.

The error seems logical in that it's saying that what I'm trying to do is in conflict, i.e. it might be that I'm trying to delete while the copy activity might still be busy, but I thought the copy activity would complete first before moving on to the Append variable activity.

I've gone as far as creating a new pipeline with one Delete activity giving the name of the file in question and I get the same result.

I'm left thinking this has to be some kind of configuration issue in Blob Storage?

Answer (score 0):

> Attempting to Delete Blob in Storage Container from Azure Data Factory Results in 409 Conflict Error

Here are the common causes that can cause this [409 Conflict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes) on the blob.

I tried it and got similar error for the blob which has snapshot present.
you need to delete them manually.

[image]

After this try to delete the file from Blob storage.

Or the other way is to use [Rest Api to delete the blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-blob?tabs=azure-ad) from ADF with

> **x-ms-delete-snapshots: {include, only} header :**
>
> - `include`: Delete the base blob and all of its snapshots.
> - `only`: Delete only the blob's snapshots, and not the blob itself.

Comment: thanks but there are no snapshots involved and at this point using the Rest Api to delete the blob is not an option in this environment